¿Existe un verbo relacionado con "exhaustivo" en español?
Estoy buscando la forma verbal de la palabra "exhaustivo", algo equivalente a "to exhaust" en inglés. Por ejemplo, quiero decir algo como:
"Esto constituye una lista exhaustiva de opciones."
pero de la forma:
"Esta lista exhausta todas las opciones."
pero la palabra "exhausta" no la encuentro en el diccionario. ¿Cuál sería el verbo o expresión más natural en español para esta idea?

Se dice agotar, o también, abarcar

Esta lista agota/abarca todas las opciones posibles.

El verbo en latín era exhaurire (exhaurio), que el español no lo heredó. Lo más parecido sería *exhaurir, pero eso sería un calco del portugués completamente censurable.

De acuerdo con tac. El verbo "agotar" es el verbo más adecuado para usar en esa frase: transmite la idea de que la lista cubre todas las opciones posibles de manera exhaustiva

Exceder

Ir más allá de lo lícito o razonable.


Esta lista excede todas las opciones

Rebasar

Pasar o exceder de cierto límite.


Esta lista rebasa todas las opciones

Extralimitar

Excederse en el uso de facultades o atribuciones.


Esta lista extralimita todas las opciones

Extremar

Llevar al extremo


Esta lista extrema todas las opciones

Superar

Esta lista supera todas las opciones

Sobrepasar

Esta lista sobrepasa todas las opciones


Mi intención no es expresar que la lista "excede", "rebasa", "sobrepasa" o "va más allá" de las opciones posibles, ya que esto daría la idea de que hay algo adicional o más de lo necesario. Por el contrario, lo que busco expresar es que la lista "contiene todas las opciones posibles", es decir, que "las agota por completo", como lo define la RAE: "exhaustivo, va. 1. adj. Que agota o apura por completo" (supongo que "agotar" se acerca a lo que busco).
El sentido es que la lista es exhaustiva, en el sentido de abarcar todo lo que existe o es posible, sin faltar ni exceder nada.
